# Как получить список методов class-а в JS?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, методы, ecmascript-6

Есть класс на ES(6), никак не могу получить список его методов, хотя очень нужно))
Вот пример:

```
class test_class {
    test_method() {
        console.log('hello world!!')
    }
}
let inst = new test_class();
console.log(Object.keys(inst))// []  wtf???
inst.test_method();// hello world!!
```

Прошу, поделитесь решением.
P.S. В firebug-e есть подсказка в виде методов класса, когда пишешь имя инстанса класса. То есть способ есть и в firebug он используется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class test_class {
    test_method() {
        console.log('hello world!!')
    }
}

inst = new test_class();
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(inst.__proto__));
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! Почти то что нужно.